# Can you help me get the right output for MergeSort using ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, mergesort

I'm new to mergeSort and I was able to solve mergeSort using integer array int[] however whenever I try to implement it using ArrayList, I can't seem to get the order right at all. I'm trying to understand why this is and what the actual solution to this would be using the same methods and variable names.

```
/* Java program for Merge Sort */
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
class MergeSort
{
    // Merges two subarrays of arr[].
    // First subarray is arr[l..m]
    // Second subarray is arr[m+1..r]
    void merge(ArrayList<Integer> al, int beg, int mid, int end)
    {
        // Find sizes of two subarrays to be merged
        int ls = mid - beg + 1;
        int rs = end - mid;

        /* Create temp arrays */
        ArrayList lft = new ArrayList(ls);
        ArrayList rgt = new ArrayList(rs);

        /*Copy data to temp arrays*/
        for (int i = 0; i < ls; i++)
            lft.add(i, al.get(beg + i));
        for (int j = 0; j < rs; ++j)
            rgt.add(j, al.get(mid + 1 + j));

        /* Merge the temp arrays */

        // Initial indexes of first and second subarrays
        int li;
        int ri;
        li = 0;
        ri = 0;

        // Initial index of merged subarry array
        int mi = beg;
        while (li < ls && ri < rs) {
            if ((int)lft.get(li) <= (int)rgt.get(ri)) {
                al.set(mi, (int)lft.get(li));
                li++;
            } else {
                al.set(mi, (int)rgt.get(li));
                ri++;
            }
            mi++;
        }

        /* Copy remaining elements of L[] if any */
        while (li < ls) {
            al.add(mi, (int)lft.get(li));
            li++;
            mi++;
        }

        /* Copy remaining elements of R[] if any */
        while (ri < rs) {
            al.add(mi, (int)rgt.get(ri));
            ri++;
            mi++;
        }
    }

    // Main function that sorts arr[l..r] using
    // merge()
    void sort(ArrayList al, int beg, int end)
    {
        if (beg < end) {
            // Find the middle point
            int mid =beg+ (end-beg)/2;

            // Sort first and second halves
            sort(al, beg, mid);
            sort(al, mid + 1, end);

            // Merge the sorted halves
            merge(al, beg, mid, end);
        }
    }

    /* A utility function to print array of size n */
    static void printArray(ArrayList al)
    {
        int arSize = al.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < arSize; i++)
            System.out.print(al.get(i) + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Driver code
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList finArr = new ArrayList();
        finArr.add(11);
        finArr.add(12);
        finArr.add(10);
        finArr.add(6);
        finArr.add(1);
        System.out.println("Given Array");
        printArray(finArr);

        MergeSort ob = new MergeSort();
        ob.sort(finArr, 0, finArr.size() - 1);

        System.out.println("\nSorted array");
        printArray(finArr);
    }
}
```

the output of the above code is:

```
Given Array
11 12 10 6 1

Sorted array
10 11 12 12 12 12 10 6 1
```

however, I don't understand why the output isn't:

```
Sorted array
1 6 10 11 12
```

Comment: You should either _only_ call `.add`, or _never_ call `.add`.  You should not have a mix between `add` and `set`.

Comment: what can be done here? where should I edit? I'm very new to this and inexperienced to say the least.

Comment: This should be an easy answer. Best is to find it out by yourself. Maybe analysing your code by debuggin would be very helpful for you. This is are some tipps on general debugging: https://www.codementor.io/@mattgoldspink/how-to-debug-code-efficiently-and-effectively-du107u9jh 
And this is how to debug using a IntelliJ IDE https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html 
When you're using another IDE you will find many articles and videos on how to debug with this IDE.

Comment: @YugantBasnet: you can accept an answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

Since you allocate the temporary arrays with an initial size, you should use `lft.set()` and `rgt.set()` to set the values instead of `.add`. Similarly, when copying the remaining elements from the temporary arrays, use `al.set()` instead of `al.add()`.

Here is a modified version:

```
/* Java program for Merge Sort */
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
class MergeSort
{
    // Merges two subarrays of arr[].
    // First subarray is arr[l..m]
    // Second subarray is arr[m+1..r]
    void merge(ArrayList<Integer> al, int beg, int mid, int end)
    {
        // Find sizes of two subarrays to be merged
        int ls = mid - beg + 1;
        int rs = end - mid;

        /* Create temp arrays */
        ArrayList lft = new ArrayList<Integer>(ls);
        ArrayList rgt = new ArrayList<Integer>(rs);

        /* Copy data to temp arrays */
        for (int i = 0; i < ls; i++)
            lft.set(i, al.get(beg + i));
        for (int j = 0; j < rs; ++j)
            rgt.set(j, al.get(mid + 1 + j));

        /* Merge the temp arrays */

        // Initial indexes of first and second subarrays
        int li;
        int ri;
        li = 0;
        ri = 0;

        // Initial index of merged subarray array
        int mi = beg;
        while (li < ls && ri < rs) {
            if ((int)lft.get(li) <= (int)rgt.get(ri)) {
                al.set(mi, (int)lft.get(li));
                li++;
            } else {
                al.set(mi, (int)rgt.get(li));
                ri++;
            }
            mi++;
        }

        /* Copy remaining elements of L[] if any */
        while (li < ls) {
            al.set(mi, (int)lft.get(li));
            li++;
            mi++;
        }

        /* Copy remaining elements of R[] if any */
        while (ri < rs) {
            al.set(mi, (int)rgt.get(ri));
            ri++;
            mi++;
        }
    }

    // Main function that sorts arr[l..r] using
    // merge()
    void sort(ArrayList al, int beg, int end)
    {
        if (beg < end) {
            // Find the middle point
            int mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;

            // Sort first and second halves
            sort(al, beg, mid);
            sort(al, mid + 1, end);

            // Merge the sorted halves
            merge(al, beg, mid, end);
        }
    }

    /* A utility function to print array of size n */
    static void printArray(ArrayList al)
    {
        int arSize = al.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < arSize; i++)
            System.out.print(al.get(i) + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Driver code
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList finArr = new ArrayList();
        finArr.add(11);
        finArr.add(12);
        finArr.add(10);
        finArr.add(6);
        finArr.add(1);
        System.out.println("Given Array");
        printArray(finArr);

        MergeSort ob = new MergeSort();
        ob.sort(finArr, 0, finArr.size() - 1);

        System.out.println("\nSorted array");
        printArray(finArr);
    }
}
```